# Site links differ on name length

Tags: seo, google-search

We have noticed when the main part of our company name is searched in Google (Premier Disability) it shows 3-4 of our pages on the very top (home, contact us, current clients, about ssdi). However, when we search using a longer and more specific version of our name (Premier Disability Services or Premier Disability Services, LLC) it only displays 1 page (home page). When searching these terms we used Chrome desktop in incognito mode.

Most searches for our company are using "Premier Disability" and not our longer version. However, we're interested in seeing why more of our pages don't show when searching a more exact term of our name. I know this is a bit nebulous of a question but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey Stephen. Can you help point me to an answered thread on the same topic? I can't find any. Like I mentioned before this was a bit nebulous of a question but couldn't find any that really gave me the answer I was looking for.

Comment: I get the same exact results for Premier Disability Services and Premier Disability including site links and a knowledge graph card. Google is picking up your brand using both. You will also see in the search query text box that your site will come up immediately for Premier Disability. This is all good! Not sure why your results are different, however, I am seeing exactly what anyone would want. Perhaps Google is seeing past results that ***you*** have made and are tailoring the results. Try Chrome's incognito mode in the future. That should help. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple yet complicated. Google's algorithm is very powerful and understands very well that most likely a person that wants to find your website would search using the simpler term 'Premier Disability'. Google assumes that a person searching the full technical name of the company looks for general company information rather than the services of the company. In example if you Google 'facebook', you'll see a simple search result page with links to facebook. If you'd search for 'Facebook Inc.', you will see corporate pages as a result and perhaps even stock ticker graphics. This also explains it similarly why for your search queries the results are different. Google isn't a phone book, Google tries to return the querying user what they are looking for based on their experience.

Comment: That does make sense. Especially since we get more searches for our company using the shorter version compared to the longer ones.Any suggestions on how we might be able to have the longer searches mirror the shorter one? Is there any way maybe through Google Search Console to tell them **P-D-S-** and **P-D-S**, LLC searches for our company are the same as **P-D-** searches? I only ask cause one of our goals is to have results for those 3 versions show the same/near same results.